# multilanguage site - how to set up desired default language?

Tags: joomla

I make site in joomla multi language - serbian and english.
I am using joomla 3.3.3 and joomla built in support for multi language.

But i want to set up that always serbian be default language.
So that always when user go to my site to be on serbian by default.
How to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set your default language at:

> Extensions -> Language Manager -> Installed - Site

You also have to add all languages that will exist to your site at:

> Extensions -> Language Manager -> Content

Please check also "Language Filter" plugin setting "Language Selection for new Visitors" to be "Site Language" instead of "Browser Settings"

Comment: @user3788491 if everything is working why not accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to choose your default language in Extensions -> Language Manager ...
If you dont see both English and Serbian there, you will have to install the missing one from Extensions -> Extension Manager and Install Languages (left)

Comment: Thank you for help. I see english and serbian in language manager. I click on serbian to be default, but every time that i go to my site it is first on english language. Any soultuin

Comment: use a different browser to check or clear your cookies for this website